# In Excel, COUNTIF() not working with constant defined string[]

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, constants, countif

This question is an expansion on https://superuser.com/questions/601419/in-excel-how-do-i-check-if-a-cell-is-in-a-list-of-values-a-range-of-cells .

I'm trying to do `=COUNTIF(name,G6)` and when name refers to some cells, it works fine, but when it refers to my constant string array it gives `#VALUE!`

My constant string array (using the name manager) is `={"192.168.3.2","192.168.3.10"}`... etc, and that may be my problem.  But ironically, if I set cell contents to that array and reference the cells, it works fine.

Thanks

Comment: COUNTIF doesn't support using a constant string array that is definied in the Name Manager. You should consider putting this in a portion of your excel file and creating a named range using those cells. Is there a reason you don't want to do that?

Comment: The defined array will be anywhere from 256 to 256^3 elements.  My spreadsheet has several thousand lines, but the two numbers are completely unrelated.  But yes, I could just stick it on the end if it wasn't an official report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT` like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1*(name=G6))
```

Comment: Works! Thanks!  They won't let me accept the answer for another 10 minutes.  Hopefully I don't forget to do so.